# Polly: wrap AsyncFallbackPolicy<TResult> with AsyncFallbackPolicy

Tags: c#, fallback, polly, retry-logic

I want to wrap a combination of `AsyncFallbackPolicy <- AsyncFallbackPolicy<bool> <- AsyncRetryPolicy`.

Wrapping `AsyncFallbackPolicy<bool> <- AsyncRetryPolicy` works fine and the resulting PolicyWrap is `AsyncPolicyWrap<bool>`. But as soon as I add AsyncFallbackPolicy I get the following error:

> You have executed the generic .Execute method on a
>   non-generic FallbackPolicy.  A non-generic FallbackPolicy only defines
>   a fallback action which returns void; it can never return a substitute
>   TResult value.  To use FallbackPolicy to provide fallback TResult
>   values you must define a generic fallback policy
>   FallbackPolicy.  For example, define the policy as
>   Policy.Handle.Fallback(/* some TResult
>   value or Func<..., TResult> */);

I execute the policy via `await policyWrap.ExecuteAsync(async () => await ...`

I couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue. Is it possible to wrap like that? If yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to mix generic and non-generic Fallback policies in a PolicyWrap.  You should move the behaviour intended for the non-generic `AsyncFallbackPolicy` into the generic `AsyncFallbackPolicy<bool>`.

*Explanation*: When the `AsyncFallbackPolicy<bool>` is included in the PolicyWrap, it creates an `AsyncPolicyWrap<bool>` which can only be used to execute delegates asynchronously returning `bool`.

A non-generic `AsyncFallbackPolicy` cannot participate in an execution asynchronously returning `bool` for the reasons stated in the error message:

> A non-generic FallbackPolicy only defines a fallback action which returns void; it can never return a substitute TResult value.

IE If the non-generic `AsyncFallbackPolicy` was invoked (if the conditions of its Handle clauses were met), it only contains code to asynchronously return `void` ... but `void` is not a permissible return value for type `bool`, so the execution does not make sense ... so Polly does not permit it.